# Open Excel File on Azure VM with Powershell Script Sent from Local Computer

Tags: azure, powershell-remoting, psexec

Can someone show how I can open an Excel document and show it visually on an Azure virtual machine using a Powershell script sent from my local machine?  I have already figured out how to run Powershell script on the VM through the AzureVM module but am running into the issue of Windows not allowing remote Powershell users to interact with a user interface.  Notes:

- I have tried PSEXEC with no luck. This may be the way to go, but I have had no luck getting it to actually work.
- I am not smart, so please use the most dumbed-down terminology as possible.
- My end goal is exactly that stated above - nothing more nothing less.

Riches and honor to the one who can solve this.

Comment: I'm confused. Do you simply want to remote desktop ON TO the VM and then View the Excel document? What is the purpose of this PowerShell script?

Comment: no way in powershell remoting(you can only see a process of notepad), you'd better use the psexec.

Comment: I apologize for the slow response, I was sick and got behind in some things. I appreciate your replies! Basically what I want the powershell script to do, which runs from my machine, is to initialize a VBA macro to run. The way I initialize it is via opening an Excel workbook. However, what @IvanYang said seems to be correct.  The problem is, I don't understand how to use psexec.  Do I use it with Powershell or is it a completely different tool?  How do I access an Azure VM with psexec (I am currently using the AzuremRM Module for commands)?

Comment: psexec is a tool, you can google it for usage, it's easy to use. But I have a problem when use it for remote execution for azure vm, due to remote configuration on azure vm(I can use psexec for other machines). If I have some update, will let you know.

Comment: Yes, I would love to know how to use it with Azure!  Maybe I need to update my question to reflect that.  Thank you Ivan.